# Virtual Assistant only takes voice input one time

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am coding a virtual assistant, everything is fine it listens to my audio input and responses correctly, but when i run the programme it only takes my command one time and the programme ends. I can't figure out where should I use the while loop so that the programme continues until i ask it to end. I tries addding while loops in different function but none seem to work.

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx3 as tts
import subprocess
import datetime
import webbrowser
import time


now = datetime.datetime.now()

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

speaker = tts.init()

x = speaker.getProperty('voices')
speaker.setProperty('voice', x[1].id)

y = speaker.getProperty('rate')
speaker.setProperty('rate' , 175)


def record_audio(ask = False):
    
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as mic:
        if ask:
            tts.speak(ask)
        print("listening")
        
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(mic , 0.05)
        audio = recognizer.listen(mic)
        
        try:
            voice_data = recognizer.recognize_google(audio , language = "en-IN")
            
        except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
            tts.speak('Sorry, I did not understand what you just said. Please try again.')

        except speech_recognition.RequestError:
            tts.speak("Sorry, my speech service is down for the time being. Please try again later.")
        
        return voice_data


def responses(command):

    if 'hello' in command:
        tts.speak("hello sir, how can I help you.")

    elif  'what is your name'  in command:
        tts.speak("My name is Otto Octavius") 

    elif  'time' in command:
        tts.speak(now.strftime("%I:%M:%S"))

    elif 'date' in command:
        tts.speak(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

    elif 'open' and 'telegram' in command:
        tts.speak("opening telegram")
        subprocess.Popen("D:\My Folder\My Softwares\Telegram Desktop\Telegram.exe")

    elif 'close' and 'telegram' and 'window' in command:
        tts.speak("closing telegram")
        subprocess.call(["taskkill","/F","/IM","Telegram.exe"])
    
    elif 'open' and 'binance' in command:
        tts.speak("opening binance")
        subprocess.Popen("D:\My Folder\My Softwares\Binance\Binance.exe")

    elif 'close' and 'binance' in command:
        tts.speak('closing binance')
        subprocess.call(["taskkill" , "/F" , "IM" , 'Binance.exe'])

    elif 'file explorer' in command:
        tts.speak("opening file explorer")
        webbrowser.open('C:/Users/arfee/Downloads')

    elif 'my folder' in command:
        tts.speak('opening my folder')
        webbrowser.open("D:\My Folder")

    elif 'search' in command:

        search_object = record_audio("What do you want me to search for?")
        url = ("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + search_object)
        tts.speak('Searching for ' + search_object)
        webbrowser.get('C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s').open_new_tab(url)
    
        



tts.speak("Welcome, how can I help you")

command = record_audio()
responses(command)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this in an infinite loop -

```
while True:
  command = record_audio()
  responses(command)
```

Comment: P.S I am also a Spider-Man fan

Comment: I tried this, but after this the programme only responded to my first command and then it just sat still (The while loop worked but the programme was not responding to my 2nd audio input)

Comment: no problem.....